# How to further continue if specific event is not present using powershell

Tags: powershell

i have a script which reads events from event log. But when particular event is not present there it throws an error , instead for a blank data.

**My Code:**

```
$eventID_1=512
$eventID_2=507
$eventID_3=207
#getting event details 
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health"; id=$eventID_1}
$events2 = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Storage-ClassPnP/Operational"; id=$eventID_2}
$events3 = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-StorageSpaces-Driver/Operational"; id=$eventID_3}

# get the first event raw XML
$event = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()
$event2 = [xml]$events2[0].ToXml()
$event3 = [xml]$events3[0].ToXml()
```

**Error: Cannot index into a null array.**
[image: error image]

What changes should i make so that when no event found just filled with blank data.

*Any help will be thankful.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to avoid indexing into a variable when it is `$null`.

For **Windows PowerShell 5.1** and older you could use an inline `if` statement like this:

```
$event = [xml]( if( $events ) { $events[0].ToXml() } else { '' } )
```

**PowerShell (Core) 7+** provides a simplified syntax using [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false) `?`:

```
$event = [xml]( $events ? $events[0].ToXml() : '' )
```

In both cases we take advantage of the fact that `$null` evaluates to `$false` in a boolean context.